# Metamask mobile browser not injecting window.ethereum

Tags: metamask

I'm having an issue where Metamask's mobile browser simply isn't injecting window.ethereum at all into my website. This is extra confusing since I'm doing everything the same way I did in a previous website that worked fine.

```
        if (window.ethereum) {
            this.handleEthereum();
        } else {
            window.addEventListener('ethereum#initialized', this.handleEthereum, {
                once: true,
            });
        }
```

To confirm that window.ethereum is never injected I also just output it on the screen and it's stays undefined indefinitely.

Everything works completely fine using a desktop browser of course. It's only an issue with metamask's mobile browser.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm experiencing the same issue